# Persist a OneToMany entity with generated IDs in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I have an entity, **Question**, which I want to persist into a database. Each question is referenced by some **Answers** through the **questionId** field.

Both entities have an ID field, which is generated automatically when persisted. Here is the simplified code for the entities:

**Question.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max=1000, message="Text too long")
    @NotNull(message="Field text cannot be null")
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "questionId")
    private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

**Answer.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max=255, message="Text too long")
    @NotNull(message="Field text cannot be null")
    private String text;

    @NotNull(message="Field questionId cannot be null")
    private Integer questionId;
}
```

So to persist a Question object with some Answers in it, I create those objects without the ID field, which will be generated automatically. The Question object is serialized from a JSON in the **QuestionController**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/questions")
public class QuestionController {
    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public void createQuestion(@RequestBody Question question){
        questionRepository.save(question);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I also have to leave the **questionId** field empty, since I don't know it until it is written into the database. This causes the transaction to throw an error requesting a value for that field.

By now the only solution I have come up with is removing the Answers from the Question and, once persisted, fill the questionId values and save the Answers separately.

Is there any way of making these transactions at once?

Comment: You don't use an `Integer` field to refer to the question. Either you leave it out completely (making it a one directional association from Question to Answer), or make it a reference to a `Question` object (making it a bidirectional association). See a tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the concept of an entity and a DTO (data transfer object).

For example, you can create a new `QuestionDTO` object as the body contract of your method in your controller.
After being parsed and validated by your framework, you convert (see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter) it to your entity object.
After that, you can safely save your entity.

```java
@Data
public class QuestionDTO {

    @Size(max=1000, message="Text too long")
    @NotNull(message="Field text cannot be null")
    private String text;

    private List<AnswerDTO> answers;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class AnswerDTO {

    @Size(max=255, message="Text too long")
    @NotNull(message="Field text cannot be null")
    private String text;

}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/questions")
public class QuestionController {
    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public void createQuestion(@RequestBody QuestionDTO questionDTO){
        Question question = convert(questionDTO);
        questionRepository.save(question);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given my experience, you are simply modeling your entities the wrong way.
As said in another comment, it is important to know what your use cases will be. 
For instance, when you are modeling Question/Answer, there will be a lot of cases where you will use your Question, and only the Question, and using the relationship with Answer to display them. But accessing the question from its answer it not likely to happen...

So, how do you do that ? Have you heard the concept of Aggregate Root and Value Object ? That's pretty easy. Here how you can design your relationship Question/Answer:

1. Create a class Answer, and use the `@Embeddable` annotation. Thus, hibernate will not try to create a table to store your answers, but you can use this to help hibernate mapping the best way.

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class Answer {
    private String text;
}
```

That's it, that is all you need to represent your **Value Object** `Answer`.

2. Create your entity `Question`, with a list of `Answers` (note I removed your contraints annotation, but feel free to use them):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @AttributeOverride(name = "text", column = @Column(name = "answer_text"))
    private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

- `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` is mandatory for Hibernate to know that it will need to store a List of `Answer`, thus, creates a Table to store an infinite number of answers for your question.
- `@AttributeOverride(name = "text", column = @Column(name = "answer_text"))` is here to say to Hibernate : please store the value of the attribute `text` of my `Answer` class, and store this value into a column whom name is `answer_text`.

What to do next ? Create a `Controller` and `Repository` and try posting a question.

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/questions")
    public void postQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        repository.save(question);
    }

    @GetMapping("/questions")
    public Iterable<Question> questions() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Integer> {}
```

And finally, post your question :

```
{
    "text": "quetion text", 
    "answers": [{
        "text": "answer1"
    }, {
        "text": "answer2"
    }]
}
```

This will create your Question with it's list of answers.

Even if with the pros/cons I'll list below, I still think that is the best solution/compromise you can have:

**Pros**

- Easy to configure
- You don't have to manage the link between `Question` and `Answer`
- When you fetch a question, it is also fetching the associated `Answer`.

**Cons**

- You can not modify a particular Answer of a specific Question (but will you ever ?)
- You don't have a table representing all the answers you have in your database (but once again, will you ever)

Given the basic use case, try this.

Just so you realize, here are the tables hibernate creates with this solution:

> Hibernate: create table **question** (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), text varchar(255), primary key (id))
>   Hibernate: create table **question_answers** (question_id integer not null, answer_text varchar(255))

Just 2 tables, one **question** and one ** question_answers**...